# How to get the sum of my value based on the dates from apache ignite cache

Tags: sql, postgresql, caching, ignite

What is the best way to get the sum of my value based on the dates from the ignite cache

Im getting all the data I need from my postgres DB based on selected dates.

value is of type String in MyClass.class

```
date       | value                                     | account
01-01-2015 | 363947.5636999999987892806529998779296875 | 110589
23-08-2016 | 56985.5636999999987892806529998779296875  | 110589
30-11-2016 | 875347.5636999999987892806529998779296875 | 110589
23-11-2016 | 756247.5636999999987892806529998779296875 | 225863
```

Then I want to sum the returned value using my cache query. Whats the best way to do this?

```
IgniteConfiguration ignitionConfig = new IgniteConfiguration();
ignitionConfig.setCacheConfiguration(cfg);
Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(ignitionConfig);

IgniteCache<Integer, MyClass> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(" SELECT SUM(value) FROM MyClass WHERE");
builder.append(" date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND ");
builder.append(" account = ? ");

SqlFieldsQuery qry = new SqlFieldsQuery(builder.toString());
qry.setArgs(startDate);
qry.setArgs(endDate);
qry.setArgs(account);

try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor =  cache.query(qry)) {
    for (List<?> row : cursor){
        System.out.println("test=" + row.get(0));
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I can loop through each results but I wanted to use the SQL way first.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I get an error SUM or AVG on wrong data type for "SUM(value)"; SQL statement:
I suspect it's because its being saved as a String. Trying to convert it using to_number(value) does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the value to `double precision` or, if the whole precision is necessary, to `numeric`:

```
select sum(value::float)
from myclass
where date between ? and ? and account = ?
```

`float` with no precision specified means `double precision`

[Numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE)

Comment: Thank you so much! Was banging my head against the wall over this.

Comment: I'm getting some odd results. The date is returned as a String i.e 01-JAN-2016. Do I need to convert it into date format in order for ignite to understand it properly? Or do I need to create a custom functions class foe this?